# Sampling with Subsets and Supersets

Tags: probability

I will give the slightly easier version first, in the hopes that it will help with the complete version.

We are given $E$ elements, and $n$ subsets containing $s$ unique elements.  If we pick $r$ of the $E$ elements, how many unique [supersets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset), out of these $r$ elements, are contained in the $n$ subsets?  What I'd really like to know is the probability of getting $m$ unique supersets.

**AN EXAMPLE**

If e=4, n=3, and s=2, we have 4 elements, 3 subsets containing these elements, and the subsets are size 2.  In this case, we can label the elements $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$, and $e_4$.  Then our 3 subsets could be $\{e_1, e_2\}$, $\{e_1, e_3\}$, and $\{e_2, e_4\}$, since they're all of size 2 and all elements of the subsets are unique in each subset.

**THE SLIGHTLY HARDER VERSION**

The harder version pairs elements together.  For integer k, only $e_{2k}$ or $e_{2k+1}$ may appear in any subset, but not both.  In other words, we consider the even numbered elements to be related to the next odd element, and so only one of them can appear in a subset.  However, any element can appear in the supersets.  **GIVEN $E$, $n$, $s$, $m$, AND $r$, WHAT IS THE PROBABILITY OF GETTING $m$ UNIQUE SUPERSETS?**